# Func not returning anything?

Tags: c#, lambda

This may sound like a bit of a dumb question but how do I make a `Func<>` variable that doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Action<T>` for a delegate that takes a variable and returns `void`.

But note that you can also just declare your own delegate types if you want to. `Action<T>`, for example, is just

```
public delegate void Action<T>(T obj)
```

Comment: I don't know but is it necesary to usea delegate will the purpose not solved by only making the return type as void

Comment: You can't specify void (or Void) as a type argument.

Comment: but the question is about return type not for the agruments

Answer (score 4):

Will the Action<T> delegate work for you?

[Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You may want:

```
Action<T> a = (t) => // your code here...
```