# void Func without arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, func

There are some similar questions but not exactly like mine.

Is there a Func equivalent for a function without a return value (i.e. void) and without parameters?

The related question is [Func not returning anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973805/func-without-any-parameters)
but this does not answer for a void type.

(I need it to request actions from my view model to my view).

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: But I need to fill in a <T> type in an Action and void is not a possibility (I will edit my question, I made a mistake).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your wording is confusing. You perhaps mean "a function without **a return type** and no parameters." There is simply [System.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx).

```
Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("hello world");
action();
```

From your comment:

> But I need to fill in a `<T>` type in an Action and void is not a possibility (I will edit my question, I made a mistake).

This indicates a misunderstanding. The T in the Action delegate is an *input*. The void is the *output.* An Action delegate is inherently a delegate returning void. The T is the type of *input* it can act upon, the parameters you would then supply with arguments.

At any rate, as this answer and others show, you can have an Action delegate without any T, a delegate that takes no inputs.

Comment: Yes I completely missed that the <T> is optional. Thank you (and others) for the help.

Comment: @anthony How can I do this with .NET Framework prior 3.5. There is no delegate Action. Only delegate Action<T>.

Comment: @ph1983, prior to C# 3, you would use delegates, though C# 2.0 added support for *anonymous methods*. I do not have an example question right offhand, but you can read about the feature on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx).

Answer (score 26):

Yes, there are different overloads of `Action` taking a different number of input parameters and having a `void` return type.

```
Action               public delegate void Action()
Action<T>            public delegate void Action<T>(T obj)
Action<T1,T2>        public delegate void Action<T1,T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
Action<T1,T2,T3>     public delegate void Action<T1,T2,T3>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
...
```

The first line is what you are looking for.

Newer Framework versions have added overloads with even more arguments.
Maximum number of arguments:

- .NET Framework 2.0:    **1**
- .NET Framework 3.5:    **4**
- .NET Framework 4.0: **16**
- Silverlight:                           **16**

---

Actions have always a `void` return type. A `void` return type need not and cannot be specified as generic type parameter. By contrast, the `Func` delegates define "real" return types and have always at least one generic type parameter for the return type. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.7)

```
Func<TResult>           public delegate TResult Func<TResult>()
Func<T,TResult>         public delegate TResult Func<T,TResult>(T arg)
Func<T1,T2,TResult>     public delegate TResult Func<T1,T2,TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
...
```

---

.NET Framework 4.0 has added `in` and `out` modifiers to the generic type parameters for contravariance and covariance. See: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Examples:

```
public delegate void Action<in T1, in T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)

public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is an Action. It takes no parameters, and returns no value.